# Sum all the numbers in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a recursive function below and I was just wondering how I can create the same function but with an iterative approach (i.e. loops without recursion).

```js
function recursiveCalculate(number, sum) { // num is expected to be a string
    sum = sum || 0;
    if (number.length === 0) {
        return sum;
    }
    return recursiveCalculate(number.slice(1), sum + +number[0]);
}

console.log(recursiveCalculate('145'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is, with a nice handy demonstration:

```js
function recursiveCalculate(number, sum) {
    sum = sum || 0;
    for (i=0; i<number.length; i++) {
        sum += Number(number.charAt(i));
    }
    return sum;
}
console.log(recursiveCalculate('145'))
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input"></input>
<button onclick="console.log(recursiveCalculate(document.getElementById('input').value));">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

simply use array reduce

```js
const recursiveCalculate=num=>[...num].reduce((t,v)=>t+Number(v),0)
 
console.log(recursiveCalculate('145'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Split at each character of the passed string - then use `.reduce()` to add all the numbers together - note that a) each element is parsed into a number since it is originating from the string and b) 0 is entered as the starting integer for the summ in the reduce function.

```js
function recursiveCalculate(str){
  return str.split('').reduce(function(a, b){return a + parseInt(b);}, 0);
}

console.log(recursiveCalculate('145')); // gives 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* split (or spread) the string into individual characters, coerce them into numbers and add them together. For this `Array#reduce` is probably a natural choice:

```js
[...'145'].reduce((sum, n) => sum + Number(n), 0)
//=> 10
```

But this wouldn't account for negative numbers in strings:

```js
[...'-145'].reduce((sum, n) => sum + Number(n), 0)
//=> NaN
```

Assuming the result should be `-1 + 4 + 5 = 8` then we need to keep the minus sign with the number it belongs to:

```js
'-145'.match(/(\-?\d)/g).reduce((sum, n) => sum + Number(n), 0)
//=> 8
```

And what if you have decimals? You need to keep all the numbers *after* the `.` sign together. Fortunately we can tweak the regular expression above a little bit:

```js
'-145.08'.match(/(\-?\d|\.\d+)/g)
//=> ['-1', '4', '5', '.08']
```

Don't worry about `.08` it will convert just fine: `Number('.08') //=> 0.08`

With all this knowledge we can build `sum_str` as follow:

```js
const sum_str = str => str.match(/(\-?\d|\.\d+)/g).reduce((sum, n) => sum + Number(n), 0);

sum_str('145');
//=> 10

sum_str('-145');
//=> 8

sum_str('-145.08');
//=> 8.08
```